# jfilechooser crashes with error Win32ShellFolder2.access$200 when launched application using thirdparty user

Tags: java, jfilechooser

`JFileChooser` crashes as soon as clicked while exporting. Application works fine if it is launched with admin account, but that's against requirement.

File chooser points to the path `C:\Users\Public\Documents`. With the third-party launch user has the complete access.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser( "C:\Users\Public\Documents" );

User Permissions to path - C:\Users\Public\Documents :: canExecute :: true :: createNewFile :: false :: CanWrite :: true :: CanRead ::true

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$200(Win32ShellFolder2.java:72)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:242)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```